# My plot line and book structure don't make sense together

Tags: plot, structure

I'm writing a book and it was oraginaly going to have a different begining, but I find my new one much smoother and adds more to the overall rating. But it's a little long and I don't know how to stucture it so it's not a giant book. I could split it up into multipul books, but I already have ideas for second and third. I want it to have a structure like Hunger Games or Divergent, chapters divided into three parts.

I tried to plot it out before writing, but it just went on and on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.